# How do i create a data structure with different data type?

Tags: swift

Based on given argument data types, how do i create an element in a data structure with the given data type?

For example, i want to create Expense type object in a list when i call `Section(name: "Items", SectionArrays: [Expense])`.

However, it says data types of elements in a list should be same when i call "Section(name: "Items", sectionArrays: [Expense])" and "Section(name: "Category Totals", sectionArrays: [CategoryTotal])".

How do i handle this?

I would appreciate for any advice :)

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {
var sections = [
        Section(name: "Items", sectionArrays: [Expense]),
        Section(name: "Category Totals", sectionArrays: [CategoryTotal]),
        Section(name: "Overall", sectionArrays: [CategoryTotal])
    ]
}




struct Section {
    var name: String
    var sectionArrays: [AnyObject]

    init(name: String, sectionArrays: [AnyObject]) {
        self.name = name
        self.sectionArrays = sectionArrays
    }
}

class Expense {
    var category: String
    var description: String
    var amount: Double

    init(category:String, description:String, amount:Double) {
        self.category = category
        self.description = description
        self.amount = amount
    }
}


class CategoryTotal {
    var name: String
    var amount: Double

    init(name: String, amount: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by providing an actual array rather than just an array Type.

So, for example, you can supply it pre-initialized with members or just empty.

```
var sections = [
    Section(name: "Items", sectionArrays: [Expense(category: "Food", description: "Peanut butter", amount: 4.99)]),
    Section(name: "Category Totals", sectionArrays: [CategoryTotal]()),
    Section(name: "Overall", sectionArrays: [CategoryTotal]())
]
```

Comment: What if I only want to create an empty array without default values?? Instead of creating an actual instance I want to create an array that is type Expense.

Comment: That's what I showed with `CategoryTotal`.  It would be `Section(name: "Items", sectionArrays: [Expense]())`.